# Upload file (with raw bytes) using PHP

Tags: php, file, file-upload, curl

[image]

With a regular HTML form I can upload an image to a URL and it will upload and return fine. However when I do this in PHP

```
      $bytes = download_attachment($timeline_item_id, $attachment);
      $image = imagecreatefromstring($bytes);
        imagejpeg($image, 'tempfile.jpg');

        $files[] = '@tempfile.jpg;filename=tempfile.jpg;type=image/jpeg';
      $post = array('authenticationToken' => 'AUTH_TOKEN','media-content'=>@"tempfile.jpg");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api-ssl-5.tenthbit.com/send/media");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
```

It does not work.... Any ideas? I'm not sure that imagecreatefromstring is right. However it has created a tempfile.jpg file with a valid image.. $result is "true" instead of JSON response from FORM

The form for ref:

```
<form action="https://api-ssl-5.tenthbit.com/send/media" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="authenticationToken" id="file" value="AUTH">
<input type="file" name="media-content" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. But you did not mention what error you are getting.

I assume you are using old PHP version and it does not support '@ImageName' anymore.
If you are using PHP version 5.5.9 . Also, I assume image path is correct. So you can take help from below code block.

```
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 
$file = new CurlFile('image_path', 'mime_type', 'image_name');
$post = array('authenticationToken' => 'AUTH_TOKEN','file_array'=>$file);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api-ssl-5.tenthbit.com/send/media");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```